# How to solved 404 error deploying spring boot code on ec2 tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-404, tomcat8

I deployed spring boot war file on ec2 instance under tomcat's webapps folder (ROOT.war) and extract file but in webapps folder WEB-INF folder created instead of ROOT,I rename WEB-INF to ROOT and try to access API via postman that time 404 error showing

Answer (score 0):

Dont try to rename the Web-INF directory. Also, what port are you trying to access the application?

Comment: I also tried without changing name of WEB-INF  but not working